# Error warnings using the QGIS-plugin qlyrx

Tags: qgis, python

When trying to apply `.lyrx`symbology to two different layers using the plugin qlyrx, I get the following error warnings:

[image: Error 1]
Polygon feature

or

[image: Error 2]
Point feature

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you contacted the developer of the plugin?  May be worth submitting a bug report, via the link on the 'Details' tab at:  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qlyrx/

Comment: Good idea. I just opened a new bug report.